# What would cause a query to scan an index 9 million times?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

This query comes across from an application.  If you comment out the "IF EXISTS" clause in the WHERE clause, it runs in about 60 milliseconds.  Otherwise, it runs in about 90 seconds.  It's a search to bring back a traffic court case based on your citation number. Here's the messages when I set statisics io on.  Note the number if index scans for the ptychrg table.

> Table 'afflcd'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0,
> read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
> read-ahead reads 0.
> Table 'prtl_cscd_site'. Scan count 1, logical
> reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0,
> lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
> Table 'prcs_site_ptycd' Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
> Table 'ptycd'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0,
> read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
> read-ahead reads 0. Table 'idnt'. Scan count 4, logical reads 113680,
> physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
> physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'idntaffl'. Scan count
> 4, logical reads 23238, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob
> logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table
> 'real_casecd'. Scan count 1, logical reads 9, physical reads 0,
> read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
> read-ahead reads 0. Table 'pty'. Scan count 4, logical reads 534842,
> physical reads 440, read-ahead reads 533315, lob logical reads 0, lob
> physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'real_case'. Scan
> count 4, logical reads 208434, physical reads 22, read-ahead reads
> 207816, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead
> reads 0.
> Table 'ptychrg'. Scan count 8979168, logical reads 26937504,
> physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
> physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
> Table 'Workfile'. Scan count
> 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical
> reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table
> 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0,
> read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
> read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0,
> physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
> physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'casedspseq'. Scan
> count 4, logical reads 75434, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads
> 19813, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads
> 0. Table 'dsp'. Scan count 4, logical reads 136145, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 134236, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0,
> lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> (1 row affected)

Here's the query:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON; 

SELECT t0.case_id
     , t0.seq
     , t0.prtl_cd
     , t0.affl_id
     , t0.idnt_id
     , t0.affl_cd
     , t0.actn_cd
     , t0.case_cd
     , t0.case_secret
     , t0.case_seq
     , t0.company_name
     , t0.detainee_id
     , t0.dob
     , t0.dod
     , t0.dscr
     , t0.file_dt
     , t0.first_name
     , t0.folder_nbr
     , t0.idnt_xref_id
     , t0.ins_dttm
     , t0.last_dsp_cd
     , t0.last_dsp_dt
     , t0.last_file_dt
     , t0.last_name
     , t0.middle_name
     , t0.ofic_cd
     , t0.prfx_cd
     , t0.pty_affl_cd
     , t0.pty_cd
     , t0.pty_secret
     , t0.ptycd_dscr
     , t0.recidivist
     , t0.sffx_cd
     , t0.site_id
     , t0.sort_order
     , t0.ssn
     , t0.stat_cd
     , t0.ticket_nbr
     , t0.upd_dttm
     , t0.year
FROM eaccess_cases t0 --This is a view
--FROM dbo.DougTest t0
--FROM dbo.DougTest_ptychrg t0
WHERE (
          (t0.prtl_cd = 'PUBLIC')
          AND
          (
              (t0.ticket_nbr = 'E000220665')
              OR EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM ptychrg t1
    WHERE (
              (
                  (t0.case_id = t1.case_id)
                  AND (t0.seq = t1.seq)
              )
              AND (t1.ticket_nbr = 'E000220665'
                    AND t1.ticket_nbr IS NOT NULL 
                    )
          )
)
          )
      )
ORDER BY t0.sort_order ASC;
```

And here's the eaccess_cases view definition.  I know, the FROM clause is about 20 years out of date, but we tried writing it using JOIN syntax and it didn't change the execution plan all that much.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[eaccess_cases]
  AS 
  SELECT p.case_id 
     , p.idnt_id
     , p.seq
     , p.pty_cd
     , p.secret pty_secret
     , i.first_name
     , i.middle_name
     , i.last_name
     , i.company_name
     , i.dob
     , i.dod
     , i.ssn
     , i.prfx_cd
     , i.sffx_cd
     , i.detainee_id
     , i.folder_nbr
     , i.recidivist
     , i.idnt_xref_id
     , i.ins_dttm
     , i.upd_dttm
     , ia.affl_id
     , ia.affl_cd
     , pcs.site_id
     , r.dscr
     , r.stat_cd
     , r.file_dt
     , r.last_file_dt
     , r.case_cd
     , r.secret case_secret
     , r.year
     , r.seq case_seq
     , UPPER(ISNULL(i.last_name,ISNULL(i.company_name,' '))+' '+ISNULL(i.first_name,' ')+' '+ISNULL(i.middle_name,' ')+ISNULL(i.sffx_cd,' ')+ISNULL(i.prfx_cd,' ')+ISNULL(r.dscr,' ')) sort_order
     , r.ticket_nbr
     , r.actn_cd
     , pcs.prtl_cd
     , pc.dscr ptycd_dscr
     , CASE WHEN ia.affl_id != p.idnt_id THEN ia.affl_cd ELSE NULL END AS pty_affl_cd
     , dsp.dsp_cd AS last_dsp_cd
     , dsp.dsp_dt AS last_dsp_dt
     , r.ofic_cd
     , ISNULL(pcs.CASE_CD_DSCR, rc.DSCR) AS casecd_dscr
  FROM dbo.real_case r 
     , dbo.real_casecd rc
     , dbo.pty p 
     , dbo.ptycd pc
     , dbo.idnt i 
     , dbo.idntaffl ia
     , dbo.afflcd af
     , casedspseq cds
     , dsp dsp
     , eservices.prtl_cscd_site pcs
     , eservices.prcs_site_ptycd psp
 WHERE r.case_id = p.case_id
   AND rc.case_cd = r.case_cd
   AND p.pty_cd = pc.pty_cd
   AND (p.secret = 0 OR p.secret IS NULL)
   AND (r.secret = 0 OR r.secret IS NULL)
   AND p.idnt_id = ia.idnt_id
   AND ia.affl_id = i.idnt_id
   AND ia.affl_cd = af.affl_cd
   AND af.index_chk = 1
   AND (ia.affl_id=ia.idnt_id
            -- or ia.affl_id in (select affl_id from idntaffl ifl where ifl.idnt_id=p.idnt_id)
            OR ia.affl_id IN (SELECT affl_id FROM ptyaffl pfl WHERE pfl.case_id=p.case_id AND pfl.seq=p.seq)
       )
   AND r.case_id = cds.case_id AND cds.case_id = dsp.case_id AND cds.seq = dsp.seq
   AND r.case_cd = psp.case_cd AND psp.pty_cd = p.pty_cd
   AND pcs.prtl_cd = psp.prtl_cd
   AND pcs.site_id = psp.site_id
   AND pcs.case_cd = psp.case_cd
   AND pcs.active = 1;

GO
```

[Here's the link to the execution plan.](https://www.brentozar.com/PasteThePlan/?id=rJAVHxGTO)

Comment: A query plan is going to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Evolve - NO ONE should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). And just because the change did not "improve" anything does not negate the need to do so. And I would guess there is a logic error in the query but that is impossible to know without DDL.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, this is a vendor database.  We thought the old style code was crazy, too.  However, so far we haven't figured out a way to write the view that improves things, so we're leaving it alone until we do.

Answer (score 0):

As Ben mentioned, having your **actual execution plan** for both test cases of the query would be most helpful. Barring that, the `EXISTS` clause is likely needing to evaluate your logic for every row in the tables involved in that subquery. Re-writing the `EXISTS` clause in a more relational way would likely fix the issue.

Comment: How do I add the execution plan to the question?  I agree, the EXISTS clause seems to be the culprit.  However, we haven't figured out a better way to write it yet.

Comment: @Stonebreaker You can use [Paste The Plan](https://www.BrentOzar.com/PasteThePlan) to upload the XML for it and then link it in your original question. See [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/retrieving-sql-server-query-execution-plans/) on how to access your execution plan and the XML for it.

Comment: Execution plan link posted.  ¡Muchas Gracias!